Schwartz theorem
Can i relax the conditions on f of the Schwartz theorem in real analysis?
That is: if $f: \Omega \to R^2$, s.t $f \in C^2(\Omega)$, then i can change the order of derivatives and the result is the same.
Can i ask for something less than $C^2(\Omega)$? Like $f \in H^2(\Omega)$, that is the space of functions in $L^2(\Omega)$ which also have first and second derivative in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Let $f\in H^2(\Omega)$, and consider a test function $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Then, by definition of the weak derivative we have
$$ \int_{\Omega} \partial^2_{kj}f\phi\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega f\partial^2_{kj}\phi\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega f\partial^2_{jk}\phi\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega \partial_{jk}^2f\phi\,\mathrm{d}x, $$
using Schwarz's theorem in the second equality. Thus, $\partial^2_{kj}f = \partial^2_{jk}f$.
